# How to customize the highlight height with soul

Tags: soul

Is it possible to customize the height of the highlighting with the `soul` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
 \hl{game}
\end{document}
```

I would like to reduce a bit the height of the highlighting both from the top and from the bottom, is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
 \def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
 \setul{}{2ex}%         !!!change this value!!! default is 2.5ex
 \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
 \SOUL@stpreamble
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \hl{(after) game}
\end{document}
```

[image]