# Transparent colorbox with no text

Tags: spacing, colorbox, transparent

This is related to [Vary transparency of colorbox in a sentence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443156/vary-transparency-of-colorbox-in-a-sentence)

I would like to have a transparent colorbox for some overlay and this attempt is not working

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul,xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}
\sethlcolor{red}
\begin{document}

\hl{This is}%
\transparent{0.1}{\hl{\hspace{5cm}}}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?  In other words, what is the result supposed to look like?

Comment: Note: `\hl{\hspace{5cm}}` does not appear to valid syntax, even in the absence of the `transparent` package.

Comment: The result is supposed to look like a "yellow" 5cm semitransparent rectangle

Comment: Since you cannot use `\hspace` in the `\hl` argument, perhaps an alternative is to use a `\rule`, as I show in my answer.  You can adjust the rule depth and height to suit.

Answer (score 1):

I point out that

```
\hl{\hspace{5cm}}}
```

produces an error, regardless of the use of transparency.  However, one can use a `\rule` to achieve a blank field and with the added use of `\transparent`, that colored rule field can become transparent.

After some confusion on my part seemingly related to multiple compilations required for the `transparent` package, it seems to work.

Take this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul,xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}
\sethlcolor{red}
\begin{document}

\leavevmode
\rlap{hi mom how are you?}%
\transparent{.6}{\hl{xyz}\color{yellow}\rule{1in}{2ex}}
\end{document}
```

I get something that looks like I would expect.

[image]

If I change the `\transparent` parameter to .1 and perform the requisite numbers of compilations, the result changes to

[image]

which also follows what the package is apparently supposed to do.  As the transparency approaches unity, the red and yellow fields become opaque.

Comment: You have to compile twice, transparent uses the aux-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I should have mentioned that it made no difference in my example...though I will have to check that MikTeX wasn't auto-cleaning out the aux file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is not cleaning out the aux.  Therefore, I stand by my report.

Comment: well it works for me, and it is curious that you use 0 for opaque, that should be 1. Can you show your log-file? And how do you compile?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now I am the one confused.  All of a sudden, I can't recreate the problem.  I am going to eliminate such talk from my answer unless and until I can figure out what I was doing. wrong.